# address specified by user different from that registered as Redirect URI while using omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I had registered "http://example.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback" as the callback URI with Google. This works fine if the user comes to the website with the address "example.com" but if the user comes with "www.example.com", Google returns an error saying that this URI is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the following line to config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://example.com"
```

Now omniauth with use "http://example.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback" as the redirect uri irrespective of how the user reached the website.